# ExtensionProcessor error on every page in MediaWiki 1.25.1

Tags: php, mediawiki

I have the following error appearing on every page on my Wiki. Normally, I would disable error display, but since I'm still developing the site, I don't want to do this, I'd rather fix the error.

> Warning: array_merge_recursive(): Argument #1 is not an array in
>   /var/www/html/includes/registration/ExtensionProcessor.php on line 294

I'm running the latest version of **MW - 1.25.1** and have the following extensions installed:

- Maintenance Shell
- TopTenPages
- DynamicPageList
- HitCounter
- UniversalLanguageSelector
- VisualEditor

How can I resolve this? I'm not sure where to begin troubleshooting.

Comment: If you disable all extensions, do you get the same error?

Comment: To begin troubleshooting, look at what the argument being passed to ExtensionProcessor is expected to be. The chances are it is null instead of an array, which would suggest that something such as a config option is missing.

Comment: Interesting commit to the source here: https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/commit/9cdf419be56d3568254ee9a3e7210f9ff096cca6

Comment: I ran into the same problem after upgrading to the newest MediaWiki 1.25.1, still getting the same error even after disabling all the Extensions.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've run into [this bug](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T102523): "Setting non-array attributes in extension.json results in unhelpful error messages"

Whilst the error message is unhelpful, the solution is to find the offending item in extension.json

Comment: Ah great, thanks, how can I identify the issue in the extension.json file? I have a suspicion as to which one it might be, just need to know what to look for!

Comment: OK, it's the HitCounter plugin that's causing this. Here's the source. What do I need to change?

https://git.wikimedia.org/blob/mediawiki%2Fextensions%2FHitCounters/d13df1ed64631457eb50856ce44a454f933a5f8e/extension.json

Comment: Could be [T102522](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T102522) if you are using an outdated version of MediaWiki.

Answer (score 1):

Found some related cause of the problem.

It appears the Array will fail if you have more than 5 skins loaded in LocalSettings.php

for example if you have specified:

```
wfLoadSkin( 'CologneBlue' );
wfLoadSkin( 'Modern' );
wfLoadSkin( 'MonoBook' );
wfLoadSkin( 'Vector' );
wfLoadSkin( 'Gamepress' );
```

then you will not get the error message, but the momment you add the 6th or more skin, then you'll see that error message

```
wfLoadSkin( 'CologneBlue' );
wfLoadSkin( 'Modern' );
wfLoadSkin( 'MonoBook' );
wfLoadSkin( 'Vector' );
wfLoadSkin( 'Gamepress' );
wfLoadSkin( 'Bouquet' );
wfLoadSkin( 'DuskToDawn' );
wfLoadSkin( 'WPtouch' );
wfLoadSkin( 'Dusk' );
```

Also, some skins will still cause the problem, when loaded along with other skins like

```
wfLoadSkin( 'WPtouch' );
wfLoadSkin( 'Dusk' );
```

Works okay when loaded by itself, but the error still shows up, while included with default skins and Gamepress or Bouquet.

At the moment it's a mix and match if you want to use different skins for mobile and PC.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the error appeared after I loaded HitCounter and TopTenPages, but I believe it would happen any time you load 2 or more extensions with the wfLoadExtension hook in Mediawiki 1.25.1.

I was able to fix this error by adding `'manifest_version',` after line 83 (`'AutoloadClasses',`) in mediawiki/includes/registration/ExtensionProcessor.php.

This was based on [change 218787](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/#/c/218787/1/includes/registration/ExtensionProcessor.php).